# Drools 7.2: Building a rule engine (monitor mode and high-performance)

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie

I'm building a rule engine which exits after the first rule is matched. The ordering of the rules is done using Salience, lock-on-active (to prevent re-matches) and activation-group to exit as soon as the input matches the first rule.

The business now has a new requirement for a monitor mode where the engine has to continue to match the input to a rule which is not in monitor mode.

For example:

```
Object(attr1 = 1, attr2 = 2)

monitor     Rule 1: if (attr1 = 1) 
non-monitor Rule 2: if(attr = 1 and attr2= 2)
non-monitor Rule 3: ..
```

Here, it should match both rule 1 and rule 2, but MUST(for higher-performance) exit as soon as rule 2 is matched since it's in a non-monitor mode. Monitor mode rules are just used to see if they get evaluated and we trigger events on the backend for our business purposes.

I'm currently using PackageDescBuilder, RuleDescrBuilder etc for loading our rules dynamically from the database. A simple StatelessKieSession is used to evaluate and store results within the predicate as part of the RHS.

```
    KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
    StatelessKieSession kieSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
    kieSession.execute(predicate);
```

Q: How can the new rules be built and what concepts should I explore here for this purpose?

I'm referring to this documentation here: 
https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_rule_attributes

Thanks!

Comment: It is more straightforward to call `fireAllRules(1)` to stop after the first rule having been fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any number of "monitor" rules need to be fired before rule firing should stop after the first "non-monitor" rule, the simplest approach would be to call `fireUntilHalt` and call `halt()` on the session after the first "non-monitor" has fired.

Either put a `halt()` on the end of each "non-monitor" rule or use a listener.

Comment: This should work.. i'm will check this. However, I have to switch from stateless to statefulsession.

Comment: Thanks again. Q: Can we achieve parallelism here? Is kContainer.newKieSession() the only way to handle multiple requests or can the same session be re-used by creating one kieSession with a kContainer.newStatelessKieSession(kieConfiguration);

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, another solution could be to separate the monitor and non-monitor rules in 2 different agenda-groups. The monitored rules will not have any `activation-group` attribute, and the non-monitored will all share the same `activation-group` (just like you have today).

Then,when executing your rules, you make sure you set the right order of `agenda-group`so the monitored rules will fire before the non-monitored ones.

In this approach you can also use the `fireUntilHalt()` and `halt()` approach that Laue mentioned. The problems I see with that approach are:

- If you don't use `agenda-group`, you need to guarantee that all your monitored rules have a higher salience than the non-monitored ones.
- You need to add a rule with the lowest possible salience to `halt()` for the situations where you don't have any match on your non-monitored rules.

Hope it helps,

Comment: The ordering of monitor and non-monitor rules can be mixed, so they can't be in different agenda-groups. Although, you are right in mentioning that the last default rule needs to have a halt no matter what. Thanks!